# Creating objects based on a specific restriction

Tags: r

How can I create the matrix `A` and the vector `B` without using the function `c()` and without manually inputting the values?

```
A .  |  1 0 0  |
     |  0 2 0  |
     |  4 0 3  |

B= 6 7 8 5 6 7 4 5 6 3 4 5
```

Comment: What is the reason you can't use `c` ?

Answer (score 3):

Here are my ideas:

**A:**

```
replace(diag(1:3), 3, 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    2    0
# [3,]    4    0    3
```

**B:**

```
rep(6:8, 4) - rep(0:3, each=3)
# [1] 6 7 8 5 6 7 4 5 6 3 4 5
```

Comment: `B` variation - `rep(6:3,each=3) + rep(0:2,4)`

Comment: I thought this was going to be a fun puzzle with many answers, but I guess not. :(